# There is nothing new in this patent. WfMS and BPM platforms have been known for decades

Tags: prior-art-request, international

In reference to the patent: [CA2829469A1](https://www.google.com/patents/CA2829469A1)

BPM (Business Process Management) and WfMS (Workflow Management System) technologies, implementations, platforms, COTS solutions, and application have been known for decades, with numerous systems implemented in variety of verticals, including real estate. I do not see why this particular patent is different from prior art?
Examples of prior art: ManyWho (now Boomi's Workflow Automation). This prior art provides a low-code application development platform to rapidly build scalable and secure solutions. With this offering, you can build and deploy workflow applications, from simple to sophisticated, through a modern, native-cloud platform.There are thousands of other IT applications that are implemented on the basis of known business workflow engines.

Comment: Hint, this is an application not a patent. Are you looking for a prior art request?

Answer (score 1):

The document you have linked to is a patent application, not a patent. There are many applications that don't get granted. In addition, the claims in applications are often far broader than what might eventually get granted. At least for the US equivalent of this application, it looks like examination has not yet been started.

I do agree that the current claim seems both broad, vague and abstract. Although I'm not a lawyer or particularly knowledgeable in this field, I very much doubt it would be granted in its current state. There are provisions that allow you to submit prior art to patent offices so I encourage you to pursue that.